# Board of directors vs directorial board

Tags: word-choice

Which is better?

Grammatically, both appear correct to me, and I normally use the former.

Comment: I'd say 'better' is decided by the context in which the terms are used, so you might want to include a sample sentence or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" term is whatever the entity calls itself.

Most companies have a "board of directors", and that is the term used in the law relating to companies - e.g. https://www.toppr.com/guides/business-law-cs/elements-of-company-law-ii/board-of-directors-composition/.

On the other hand some organizations do have a "directorial board", e.g. http://www.gei.de/en/institute/management/directorial-board.html - but that may be an idiosyncratic English translation by a German organisation.

Certainly, many academic journals have an "editorial board," not a "board of editors," so by analogy a "directorial board" is possible, but not in common usage.